# Mocking logging output in Python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to verify logging output in a Python application that writes log messages to two handlers with different levels - stdout and a file.

Using @mock.patch to patch sys.stdout with io.StringIO I'm able to verify that appropriate messages are written there. Can I similarly target TextIO used by the logging module and put my own StringIO object there instead?

```
import io
import logging
import os
import sys
import unittest.mock

import logutils.colorize


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def _setup_logger(self, stdout_level: str, file_level: str):
        try:
            os.unlink("test.log")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

        log_stdout_handler = logutils.colorize.ColorizingStreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        log_stdout_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
        log_stdout_handler.setLevel(stdout_level)

        log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="test.log", mode="a", encoding="utf8")
        log_file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
        log_file_handler.setLevel(file_level)

        _root_logger = logging.getLogger()
        _root_logger.addHandler(log_stdout_handler)
        _root_logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)
        _root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def _log_messages(self):
        log = logging.getLogger("test")
        log.debug("debug")
        log.info("info")
        log.warning("warning")
        log.error("error")
        log.critical("critical")

    @unittest.mock.patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=io.StringIO)
    @unittest.mock.patch("?", new_callable=io.StringIO)  # <--- can I target FileHandler's io.TextIOWrapper here?
    def test_log_stdout_info_file_debug_then_messages_logged_appropriately(self, mock_file: io.StringIO, mock_stdout: io.StringIO):
        self._setup_logger("WARNING", "DEBUG")
        self._log_messages()

        stdout_output = mock_stdout.getvalue()
        stdout_lines = stdout_output.splitlines()
        self.assertEqual(len(stdout_lines), 3)  # irl i would probably regex match the messages

        file_output = mock_file.getvalue()
        file_lines = file_output.splitlines()
        self.assertEqual(len(file_lines), 5)
```

Stepping into `logging\__init.py:1054` I can see that `FileHandler`'s stream field is an instance of `_io.TextIOWrapper`, but doing `@unittest.mock.patch("_io.TextIOWrapper", new_callable=io.StringIO)` does not work. Neither does using `io.TextIOWrapper`, `logging.io.TextIOWrapper`, or `logging._io.TextIOWrapper`.

Or perhaps there's a better way of accomplishing what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting nowhere with that, so what I ended up doing was mocking `emit` functions of the log handlers (and the `_open` function of the `FileHandler`, since I don't want any log files to be created), and doing verification on the mocks.

```py
def _assertEmitted(self, emit_mock: unittest.mock.MagicMock, messages: list[str]) -> typing.NoReturn:
    self.assertEqual(emit_mock.call_count, len(messages))
    for index, message in enumerate(messages):
        self.assertEqual(emit_mock.call_args_list[index].args[0].msg, message)

@unittest.mock.patch.object(logutils.colorize.ColorizingStreamHandler, "emit")
@unittest.mock.patch.object(logging.FileHandler, "emit")
@unittest.mock.patch.object(logging.FileHandler, "_open")
def test_given_log_levels_when_logging_then_appropriate_messages_logged(self, _, file_emit, stdout_emit):
    # setup logger
    stdout_handler = logutils.colorize.ColorizingStreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stdout_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("..."))
    stdout_handler.setLevel("INFO")
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="doesn't matter", mode="a", encoding="utf8")
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("..."))
    file_handler.setLevel("DEBUG")
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.addHandler(log_stdout_handler)
    root_logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # do log calls here
    log = logging.getLogger("test")
    log.info("info")
    log.debug("debug")

    self._assertEmitted(stdout_emit, ["info"])
    self._assertEmitted(file_emit, ["info", "debug"])
```